# Pass selected data form row to next page in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to iphone, I have a tableview.I get the data of the selected row when selecting a row using the below function.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

How to pass this selected  data to next page.

Comment: here is an advice for you: Go and read some tutorials on basic iOS programming :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting a variable in the second view. When the row is selected, which means the

> -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

is called, set selected data to the variable in this function.

Then u can manipulate the variable from the second view. This is provided you instantiate the second view....

Answer (score 0):

Property synthesize the string,array,etc like this.. in `yourNextViewController.h` file

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *nextViewArray;
```

and in `yourNextViewController.m` file just Synthesize like bellow..

```
@synthesize nextViewArray;
```

and then just pass out like bellow..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      yourNextViewController *objNextView = [[yourNextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourNextViewController" bundle:nil];
      objNextView.nextViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      objNextView.nextViewArray = [yourCurrentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      [objNextView.nextViewArray retain];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:objNextView animated:YES];
      [objNextView release];
}
```

Comment: you try this with flow which i display mate??

Comment: @user1790877 what you want to pass data in next view??